# Possible Bug? TableView event.index is wrong when TableView has sections

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

Below I included all code from the sample app to reproduce this issue.  To start, here is a screenshot and a description:

Here is version/platform info:

1. Titanium Command-Line Interface, CLI version 3.1.2, Titanium SDK version 3.1.3.GA
2. Titanium Studio, build: 3.1.3.201309132423
3. Tested on Win7 chrome, Mobile Web Preview

### Screenshot of app in browser

[image: app screenshot]

- If you click on "One", you'll see an alert for index 0, as expected.
- If you click on "Three", you'll see an alert for index 1, as expected.
- If you click on "Two", you'll see an alert for index 2, as expected.
- If you click on "Four", you'll see an alert for index 2, **NOT AS EXPECTED**
- And indeed, if you add more rows to the "Evens" section, they will all alert index 2.

Is this a bug?  Am I misunderstanding how indexes are supposed to work in the context of sections?

Fwiw, I have tried various different ways of creating the table (eg, adding the TableViewRows to TableViewSections first and then using appendSection), but they all have the same problem.

Also, the same problem occurs if I create the rows and sections using XML only.

Ultimately, I would like to be able to use the index of the click event as an argument to `deleteRow()`, and this works fine when trying to dynamically delete rows in the first section, but it breaks down as soon as click on anything in the second section, because the index is always the same, and `deleteRow(2)` does not even delete the first entry of the 2nd section, as you might expect (it does nothing).

### index.xml

```
<Alloy>
    <Window class="container">
        <TableView id="table" onClick="alertIndex">
        </TableView>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

### index.js

```
function alertIndex(e) {
    alert(e.index);
}

function createTable() {
    var rows = [];
    rows.push(Ti.UI.createTableViewSection({ headerTitle: "Odds" }));
    rows = rows.concat(makeTableViewArr(["One", "Three"]));  
    rows.push(Ti.UI.createTableViewSection({ headerTitle: "Evens" }));
    rows = rows.concat(makeTableViewArr(["Two", "Four"]));  
    $.table.setData(rows);
}

function makeTableViewArr(arrRowText) {
    return arrRowText.map(function(rowText) {
        return makeTableViewRow(rowText);
    });
}

function makeTableViewRow(rowText) {
    return Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
        title: rowText,
        className: "row"
    });
}


createTable();
$.index.open();
```

### index.tss

```
".container": {
    backgroundColor:"white"
},
"Label": {
    width: Ti.UI.SIZE,
    height: Ti.UI.SIZE,
    color: "#000"
} 
".row": {
    height: 75,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    color: '#000',
    font: {
        fontStyle: 'italic',
        fontSize: '16sp'
    },
}
```

## UPDATE

I've received confirmation that this is indeed a bug.  It affects *only* mobile web and not Android or iOS.  I've created [a JIRA ticket for it here](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TC-3327)